# Understanding basic code profiling

Tags: c++, optimization, performance, refactoring, visual-studio

I am trying to learn about profiling and followed this [guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx) hence i tried profiling the following piece of code on MS VS 2010 on windows 7 . I am not sure if this is the correct place to ask this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int add(int,int);

int main()
{
    int x [100];

    for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        x[i]=i;
    }

    cout<<add(2,3);

    system("PAUSE");

}

int add (int x, int y)
{
    return x+y;
}
```

I got the following results

[image]

[image]

Based on the guide , `High exclusive counts may indicate a performance bottleneck within the function itself.`

It seems that `[apphelp.dll]` and `[ntdll.dll]` had a performance bottleneck based on the high exclusive counts .

**These are my following questions , i have problems understanding the article**

1) What does inclusive samples of 70% mean ?? Does it mean 70% of the time was spent on this function . What is the significance of this ??

2) What does exclusive sample mean of 30% or 0% mean ?? What is the significance of this ??

3)For the graph , the X axis is the wall clock time , how about the Y axis ?? What is the significance of it

4) I created a function : `add(int x , int y )` , where is it in the profile report ??

5) What exactly is `[apphelp.dll]` and `[ntdll.dll]` ?? I know they are dynamic link libraries but why is it placed under function. I dont see such functions in my code

6) Why does the `Graph` , `Hot Path` , `Function doing the most individual work` change everytime i generate a new report with the same set of code

7) How should i go about finding the performance bottlenecks in my application and optimising it ??

8) Why do some functions like `_mainCRTStartup` , `[kernel32.dll]` have 0% exclusive samples , what does it mean ??

Pardon me for asking such newbie questions , I am new to code profiling

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not seeking a code review, but asking how to use a tool.

Comment: Whatever you do, pay no attention to exclusive time. Instead, look at inclusive time. Reason - inclusive time includes exclusive time, plus it includes time spent in subordinate calls. In "real" software, programs can be slow either because they have lots of exclusive time, or because they make subordinate calls more than they need to. Inclusive time catches both of those. Example: people can look at exclusive time and ask "How can I speed up memory allocation" when the answer is obvious "Don't *do* so much memory allocation".

Answer (score 1):

My understanding:

1) inclusive means the time spent in this function including the time spent in function you called within this function. Ex: inclusive( main ) contains the time spent in add, exclusive ( main ) does not.

2) check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_library_files#NTDLL.DLL
   your code is basically doing nothing. most of your time is spent in system pause... your code execute 1 some nanoseconds, then it takes you some time to press return

3) It is the cpu percentage use. over 100 clock cycles how many where allocated to you program by the OS ?

4) not sure, it might have been inlined... if you use the /Fa switch to get the assembly, with optimization ( O2 ) turned on, you'll probably see that the compiler translated "cout < <  add(2,3)" by the assembly for "cout < < 5"

5) your are using system("pause") and cout. Those will call windows dll ( your os api )

6) for the graph : is your cpu doing something else ? do you use other apps whil profiling ? 
for the two others: take off the system("pause") and check if it still changes

7) you are going the right way, but this code does nothing so your app spend more time in system dll than in your code :)

8) same as above.

Try a test function that really does something, like a sort function with a compare given by pointer and your own swap function. How much exclusive time do you spend on swap() compare(..) and sort(..) functions ?

try some code like this:
http://www.ousob.com/ng/turboc/ng4686d.php

and compare some shity objects, maybe use a nasty swap function with deep copy. And I sware you'll actually see something.